# Show specific row listiview on Android (data from MySQL)

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, listview

Show a `ListView` with data in MySQL. **I want to go to a specific `listivew` row where the user's email is.**

E-mail was previously recorded in SQLite and MySQL. The `listview` includes different users with different emails.
This is my code:

```
 SimpleAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,list, R.layout.b_server_list_item,
            new String[] { Config.TAG_EMAIL,
                           Config.TAG_ID,
                           Config.TAG_FOTO,
                           Config.TAG_NOMBRE,
                           Config.TAG_PESO,
                           Config.TAG_VASOS,
                           Config.TAG_SEGUIMIENTO},
            new int[] { R.id.list_email,
                        R.id.id,R.id.foto_id,
                        R.id.Nombre,
                        R.id.Peso,
                        R.id.Vasos,
                        R.id.Seguimiento}) {

     @Override
     public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
         TextView receiverIdTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Rank);
         int pos = position+1;
         receiverIdTextView.setText("" + pos); // This all work OK

         SQLiteDatabase datos;
         datos = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase("DBMIEMBRO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
         String query_email = "SELECT * from usermail order by _id DESC limit 1";
         Cursor c_email = datos.rawQuery(query_email, null);
         c_email.moveToFirst();
         // I comproved if it has data. It has an OK display in TextView

         // My problem begins here. I don't know if is the correct way to do what I want
         String listEmail = (c_email.getString(c_email.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_EMAIL)));
         if (listEmail.equals(R.id.list_email)) {

             listView.setSelection(pos);
         }

         /.../

         return view;
     }

 };

 listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

This does not work; it displays all data, but this `listview` does not show the specific row where the user's email is. I want to check if the email stored in SQLite is in the list (display MySQL) and if it is, yes, show the specific row.

In my code I checked, and I can see that I have the same mail in one of the rows (display from MySQL) and in the `textview` (display from SQLite).

Comment: DBhelper.KEY_EMAIL should resolve to whatever the column name is and I believe it is case dependent.

Comment: mysql is totally irrelevent to this discusion

Comment: @e4c5 I nearly didn't even look because of that. :)

Comment: What does *"I comproved"* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below check is completely wrong. You're checking a string value with an integer.

```
if (listEmail.equals(R.id.list_email)) {

    listView.setSelection(pos);
}
```

Instead of that, have a mail_id handy and check against it.

More, inside getview implementing a database call will slow down your list view scroll.